# Scala's Stackable Traits and Java Decorators

Tags: java, scala, decorator, traits

Suppose I have a third-party Java interface and a decorator for it:

```
interface Foo {
    void doSomething();
}

class DecoratedFoo implements Foo {
    private final Foo foo;
    public DecoratedFoo(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
       ...
       foo.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Now, suppose I want to create a "Scala-fied" version of `DecoratedFoo` called `Decorated` (so, I can, say, create a `new FooImpl with Decorated` or somesuch):

```
trait Decorated { self: Foo =>
    val wrapper = new DecoratedFoo(self)
    abstract override def doSomething() = wrapper.doSomething()
}
```

The problem is, of course, is that if you had an instance of `Foo with Decorated`, the call to `doSomething()` would infinitely recurse, because of the delegation to `wrapper` and `DecoratedFoo`'s own internal `doSomething()`.  How can this recursion be broken?

A followup to this is if we had a second similar Java decorator, say, `Decorated2Foo` and a second Scala trait `Decorated2` along those lines.  Is it possible to have Scala's `(new FooImpl with Decorated with Decorated2).doSomething()` behave similarly to Java's `new Decorated2Foo(new DecoratedFoo(new FooImpl())).doSomething()`?